# What is the INKEY$ equivalent in C programming language

Tags: c, scanf, equivalent

I am a beginner in C programming language but I have knowledge of programming in QBasic. I make lots of small programs in Qbasic to solve my basic tasks and I am recently rewriting those programs into C .

While rewriting one of the programs I stumbled upon a problem where the computer would be able to get input but without pausing the program execution. Unfortunately, `scanf` would cause the program to wait until the user presses any key and presses enter but I need my program run and still be able to get input.

Comment: kbhit() is what I think you're looking for ... don't know basic

Comment: The words you are looking for are "asynchronous input", and the way to do that depends on the environment you are working in. Can we assume that QBasic implies DOS or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows the easiest way is [kbhit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: ... keeping in mind that it's nonstandard (by definition, since the standard provides only functions for buffered and synchronous input).