# How to flush standard input device in a .C program with VC++ compiler?

Tags: c, visual-c++, stdin, flush

What can be the best way to flush the stdin in a .C program in VC++ along with getchar()?

```
int c;
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' );
```

looks very odd to me.

```
fflush();
```

and

```
scanf ( "%*[^\n]" );
getchar();
```

is not working in VC++ in case of a .C program.

Comment: The first method is the correct way,Why do you don't want to use it?

Comment: I am searching for a way that is built-into the compiler's standard library.

Comment: There is no built-in way,In C the input is buffered, which means that when any keys are hit those are not sent to your program directly but the OS holds it backs(buffers) and sends the input to your program,this may happen at discretion of the OS.So there is no standard way of clearing an input stream.Your first example is a reasonably good way,but that may fail sometimes as well.As far as `fflush()` goes it is unsafe and you should not use it at all.

Comment: `fflush` is not what you want, it's for use with output streams ("make sure the whole buffer is actually written").

Comment: @Als: `fflush()` is perfectly safe for output streams; it's undefined for input streams.  (Well, it's "perfectly safe' in the sense that it can cause an error condition, but its behavior is defined.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: It is,The OP means input stream in this context, which would result in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Als: Understood.  My point is that your comment, "... and you should not use it at all", could easily imply that you should *never* use it.  I'm sure that wasn't your intent, but I wanted to clarify it for other readers.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks for clarifying,I am sure it will help others.Possibly,I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect a key being hit (and read it's value) - then that is an operating system feature. 'C' has no knowledge of keyboards (or any other hardware)

On windows use _kbhit()  see [What is the INKEY$ equivalent in C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279802/what-is-the-inkey-equivalent-in-c-programming-language)